# Medical Imaging in Python (PyRadiomics): Concrete steps

Tags: python

I am new to medical imaging, but I am trying really hard to replicate some former analyses within this topic out of interest (e.g., https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/26337765).  My questions are:

1. Are there any **online resources that provide step-by-step guides for performing radiomics analyses**? Not scientific articles, but beginner guides.
2. Provided TCIA data, how do I, for example, **construct the measure "*Necrosis***: dark region observed in T1 scans"? I have T1 scans and segmentation, but I don't know how to extract this specific feature. PyRadiomics allow for FOS, shape, etc.
3. Given 300 of such TCIA images, do I just do a **simple average** across all "Necrosis" scores to get the aggregate?

Comment: Hi Kim, welcome to CV! Note that 1) there's no need to say thanks at the end of the post, and more importantly 2) you should avoid asking multiple questions per thread (unless they make no sense stand-alone). Your question is interesting, but try improving it by narrowing it down, and maybe explain what exactly you mean by *step-by-step guides for performing radiomics analyses*.

Comment: In my modest opinion, this question should be open again. The doubts are useful and, therefore, will be relevant to the community.

Comment: If there is any statistical content here, please edit to clarify.